# How to add validator, regex or maskRe condition to AEM / CQ RTE (Rich Text Editor)

Tags: validation, adobe, aem, richtext, rte

Is it possible to add a validator, regex or maskRe to a RichText editor (xtype="richtext")?
I can't find this information in https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/ref/widgets-api/output/CQ.form.RichText.html

Is there any **hack / creative** solution to achieve this?

All I want to do is to validate the input text in a RTE. It is possible with a "normal" textfield, but I can't find a solution for RTE.

Answer (score 1):

You can register a validator on RTE as mentioned in the blog :
http://experience-aem.blogspot.in/2015/08/aem-61-support-required-property-on-richtext-editor-rte-of-touchui.html

Also, do remember to read all the comments there to get more clarity